# Slow query time SQL/Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, join

I am querying a rather large database with thousands of rows.  It's taking in the neighborhood of 5 minutes, whereas it should take about 5 seconds.

```
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT flights.airline, flights.flight_num,"
            + "origin_airport_code, destination_airport_code,"
            + "ticket.date, ticket.bought_date, ticket.price "
            + "FROM flights JOIN flightinfo JOIN ticket");
```

Should I be using some specific kind of join JOIN statement?

Comment: What columns are you joining on?

Comment: Please provide your create statements. It will always help us to find better solutions for your performance issues asked here. We can optimize not only your select statement, but the tables involved. By the way, welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, what your query does is it get the cartesian product of the table because you have not specified their join condition or define how the tables were related with each other.

You need to add a condition or `ON` clause every join statements, eg

```
SELECT  flights.airline, 
        flights.flight_num,
        origin_airport_code, 
        destination_airport_code,
        ticket.date, 
        ticket.bought_date, 
        ticket.price 
FROM    flights 
        INNER JOIN flightinfo 
            ON flights.colName = flightinfo.colname  -- << 1
        INNER JOIN ticket
            ON table.ColName = ticket.colName        -- << 2
```

WHERE:

```
1 >> Colname >> how the two tables:flights and flightinfo, are related
2 >> table >> I don't know where the table ticket will be joined, it is 
              either flights or flightinfo.
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the last line

```
FROM flights JOIN flightinfo JOIN ticket
```

You should INNER or LEFT join them.

Another thing you should be aware about is that if there are many tickets per flight you will get flight duplicates.

If there may be that there is no ticket for a flight then you will get no flights if using INNER join.

I guess that flightinfo always exists and it's 1:1 to flights.

So the final solution would be (based on my assumptions):

- inner join flightinfo
- left join tickets
- when parsing keep in mind that flights will be duplicated per each ticket

If tickets is your primary table and you do not need flights with no tickets then do `FROM ticket` and inner join other tables.